# Get src value from html code?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, src

I have shortcode for WordPress.

```
function url( $atts, $content = null ) {
$url = parse_url($content);
$url_new = base64_encode($content);
return '<div id="url_new"><a href="'.$url_new.'" target="_blank">'.$url_new['host'].'</a></div>';
}

add_shortcode( 'url', 'url' );
```

I need to extract SRC from $content just here

```
function url( $atts, $content = null ) {
***EXTRACT $content and get src as $url_from_src***
$url = parse_url($content);
$url_new = base64_encode($content);
    return '<div id="url_new"><a href="'.$url_new.'" target="_blank">'.$url_new['host'].'</a></div>';
}

add_shortcode( 'url', 'url' );
```

So I can use

```
[url]
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxx" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
[/url]
```

and get

```
<div id="url_new">
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxx" target="_blank">youtube.com</a>
</div>
```

But, only if it is html, if it is for example      `[url]https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxx[/url]`

It also should return

```
<div id="url_new">
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxx" target="_blank">youtube.com</a>
</div>
```

**ANSWER** (just in case someone or me need it again):

```
function url( $atts, $content = null ) {
preg_match('/src="([^"]+)"/', $content, $matches);
 if ( isset($matches[1]) ) 
     {
$url = $matches[1];
$url_parsed = parse_url($url);
$url_parsed_base = base64_encode($url);
    return '<div id="url_parsed"><a href="'.$url_parsed_base.'" target="_blank">'.$url_parsed['host'].'</a></div>';
     } else {
$url = $content;
$url_parsed = parse_url($url);
$url_parsed_base = base64_encode($url);
    return '<div id="url_parsed"><a href="'.$url_parsed_base.'" target="_blank">'.$url_parsed['host'].'</a></div>';
     }
}

add_shortcode( 'url', 'url' );
```

Thanks to Iago Melanias.

Comment: The content variable return the html code?

Comment: Yes, $content is all text inside shortcode, if you ask that. I am not an good at codding. if this is possible it would make my posting much easier. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `preg_match` function with a regular expression to get the src parameter from the html code.

```
function url( $atts, $content = null ) {
    preg_match('/src="([^"]+)"/', $content, $matches);
    $url = $matches[1];
    $parsedUrl = parse_url($url);
    return '<div id="url_new"><a href="'.$url.'" target="_blank">'.$parsedUrl['host'].'</a></div>';
}
```

And do not use `***` for comments, the php will not interpret it and will give you a error.

Comment: Thanks, works for me with few tweaks, except, what if no src, how to make it return $content if $content has no src=""

Comment: You can check if `$matches[1]` was set using `isset` function.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks a ton.